# Read from framebuffer on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer

I try to get data from default framebuffer on Android (GLES 3.1). Andriod version 6.0. Device: Levono TAB 2 A-10.
If I use glReadPixels it works fine, but I want to avoid copying data to the CPU and bind this data to a compute shader.
Code looks like this:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 300, 250);

glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 300, 250, 0);
```

After glCopyTexImage2D I get
 `ERROR: 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)` 
That from documentation means: GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the currently bound framebuffer's format does not contain a superset of the components required by the base format of internalformat.

I tried different formats of texture, but without success.

Comment: You might want to state on what devices/OS versions you are testing on.

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from `glCopyTexImage2D` and isn't hanging around from `glReadBuffer` or some other call?

Comment: Yes, I check glGetError after every gl function call (not shown in code example)